# Disable "Unclosed comment" inspection

Tags: phpstorm

Where I can disable **"Unclosed comment"** inspection in PhpStorm?
[image: Unclosed comment]

I can't find this inspection settings

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        /*// Typeahead
            var a = $.parseJSON('<?php //echo json_encode( $groups); ?>');
$('#query').typeahead({        
        local: a
});*/
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide whole file example (downloadable link) that reproduces the issue. But in general -- if it comes from the Lexer/Parser (which might be) then such errors are not supressable (but you may workaround it a bit by editing the code) -- that's why the file is needed.

Comment: @LazyOne I add code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a known issue.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22461 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Possible workaround -- use single line comments instead of block comments.

Comment: Please see what can you say on [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789536/ignore-some-classes-in-project-from-suggestion-in-code-complete)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. PHPStorm seems to have trouble with inspecting mixed HTML/PHP files.

Until they fix the issue, you can disable real-time inspections:

[Picture I took as a test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NRWG.png)

If this concerns you, you can always just run a manual code inspection by navigating the menus to the option:

Code > Inspect Code

Comment: Thanks for advance, but I prefer real time inspection. I hope JetBrains fix this issue soon