# Ignore some classes in project from suggestion in code complete

Tags: phpstorm

I have file **email.php** where I have markup and declaration of class **email_db** which I never used in another place. But when I use autocomplete when I try type **empty** by 2 first letters **em** I often see this class as suggestion.

Is it possible to ignore some class names from code complete feature?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no option for that. The only thing you can try - is to move the file with class declaration to a folder marked "excluded".

Answer (score 0):

**Configuring imports**
**To configure classes to be excluded from import

> 1. Open the Settings/Preferences dialog box, and under the Editor / General node, click Auto-Import.
> 2. On the Auto-Import page, click `Alt+Insert`.
> 3. In the dialog box that opens, type the name of the **class** or a whole **package** to be excluded, and click OK. 
>      Use **Alt+Insert** and **Alt+Delete** to manage the list of classes and packages that IntelliJ IDEA shouldn't place to the suggestion list.
> 4. Apply changes and close Settings/Preferences dialog.

**Original Link**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/excluding-classes-from-auto-import.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: that is not what I want. This option exist only in IntelliJ IDEA and affect to Java class import record on code writing if it needed